# Does anyone know of a text editor that allows you to indent highlighted chunks of code all at once?

Tags: html, text, editor, block, indentation

I am extremely OCD when it comes to the layout of my code, and it's a pain to press the down arrow key and Tab a hundred times in a row. Does anyone use a text editor that has the function of indenting chunks of code at the same time? Such as, if I have this:

```
<div>
    <img src="blahblah" style="float:left" />
    <span>Hey it's a picture.</span>
</div>

<div>
    <img src="somephoto" style="float:right" />
    <span>Another picture</span>
</div>
```

...then I come back later and want to wrap both divs in another div, but it comes out like this:

```
<div>
<div>
    <img src="blahblah" style="float:left" />
    <span>Hey it's a picture.</span>
</div>

<div>
    <img src="somephoto" style="float:right" />
    <span>Another picture</span>
</div>
</div>
```

When I want it to look like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <img src="blahblah" style="float:left" />
        <span>Hey it's a picture.</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="somephoto" style="float:right" />
        <span>Another picture</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously this is a minor example, but when it comes to large files this becomes quite a hassle. I use Bluefish on Ubuntu and Notepad++ on Windows, and neither seem to come with the capability to indent a block of code all at once. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Any decent text editor, including Notepad++, can do this.

Select the lines and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Yup go with Notepad++, its brilliant. Dont forget Shift + Tab too though, just as useful:)

Answer (score 0):

Any decent text editor will have this functionality implemented into the editor.

They already mentioned [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), but there's also [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) which is available for Windows and Linux (Also has the ability for auto close tags), [Droidedit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.droidedit&hl=en) for Android,[Smultron](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smultron/) for OS X users, and if you love web based apps like myself there's the [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) JavaScript library.

If you want to indent a large selection of code use <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
If you want to unindent/outdent a large selection of code use <kbd>SHIFT + Tab</kbd>.

Becomes very helpful. Also <kbd>CTRL + F</kbd> to find text, <kbd>CTRL + H</kbd> to replace text (Notepad++ has a replace all function, but Geany does not)